# Any BPEL parser and XML generator together?

Tags: xml, parser-generator, bpel

I want to generate/write and then parse (write & read) the bpel process (xml). Is there any way api to this, something like wsdl4j... ?

thx
adnan

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you mean about generating BPEL, but parsing and writing can be handled masterfully by some classes of the [Eclipse BPEL Project](http://www.eclipse.org/bpel/). Go there to take a look and download the source code. If you look through the mailing lists, you will find that quite a few before you have asked about where exactly to locate this functionality.